# Has My mead gone south?

Tags: mead, contamination, honey, help

This is rather my first time doing a mead. It has been a month since i put it up for fermentation. Its been locked in a relatively stable temperature and totally dark enviroment.

Today, after a full month, I opened it up to check on it and the fermenting has stopped. I have dead yeast at the bottom of the containter, and the mead is clear. But, the part that is troubling me is that along the neck i have this amber coloured residue. It looks like a very moist foam. Not bubbly but not neccisarily wrong looking. It doesnt drape down into the mead and I have no sickly smells. I've had it airlocked and used properly sanitized utenciles when brewing.

Is this normal "mead foam" or is it the sign of an infection?

http://postimg.org/image/wn0swbi6b/e1cd06f7/

Answer (score 5):

Contamination('infection') will usually make a ring right at the surface of the wort/must etc. Anything above the liquid would have come from the initial fermentation foam (or maybe from getting something in the neck of the bottling when filling, such as dry yeast).

Mead will generate a little foam at the beginnning, so it's probably nothing to worry about.

To be sure take a sample and taste it. If it tastes OK, then don't worry. And, if the mead is still very sweet and you want more fermentation, this would be a good time add nutrients.

Comment: +1 for the nutrients on sweetness suggestion.  You might want to clarify that the OP should sample the mead, not the foam residue.  Also "if it tastes OK" is a little vague.  Warn him that the alcohol might be a little sharp in a young mead and that that is not a problem.